# I'm trying to call void functions in another function, but I don't know how to properly place them

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// these should have all of my declared functions

int start(char x, char y, char z);
void pim();
void pmm();
void login();
void createa();

//my assignment wants me to have only one function used

int main()
{
    start(pim(), login(), createa());

    return 0;
}

//This should be the start of the code

void pim()
{
    cout << "Please select a letter from the menu below:" << endl;
    cout << "l - Login" << endl;
    cout << "c - Create New Account" << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
}

// this is to post a menu after you make the first choice above

void pmm()
{
    cout << "d - Deposit Money" << endl;
    cout << "w - Withdraw Money" << endl;
    cout << "r - Request Balance" << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
}

//this is to login to the account

void login()
{
    cout << "Okay, you're in" << endl;
}

// this is to create an account

void createa()
{
    int id = 0;
    int password = 0;

    cout << "create an ID of two numbers" << endl;
    cin >> id;

    cout << "Make a password of 4 numbers" << endl;
    cin >> password;
}

// Starts and is basically the entire project

int start(char x, char y, char z)
{
    char pim = x;
    cout << pim;

    int choice = 0;
    char select = '\0';

    cout << "Enter the choice that you want:";
    cin >> choice;

    if(select == 'l')
    {
        choice = 1;  
    }
    else if( select == 'c')
    {
        choice = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        choice = 3;
    }

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << y << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << z << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "This is not a command" << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: `start(pim(), login(), createa());` does not make sense since the functions are `void`.

Comment: Have you learned about returning values from functions? That seems like what you want to do.

Comment: Function arguments are also not guaranteed to be evaluated left-to-right. Those three functions could execute in any order.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is **function pointers**

Comment: Welcome. Please, improve your question by adding some details and actually the question. Explain, what are you doing in general, what do you want to achieve, what is the problem and what have you tried to do already

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I didn't use return functions properly

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **function pointers**, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// these should have all of my declared functions

int start(void (*x)(), void (*y)(), void (*z)());
void pim();
void pmm();
void login();
void createa();

//my assignment wants me to have only one function used

int main()
{
    start(&pim, &login, &createa);

    return 0;
}

//This should be the start of the code

void pim()
{
    cout << "Please select a letter from the menu below:" << endl;
    cout << "l - Login" << endl;
    cout << "c - Create New Account" << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
}

// this is to post a menu after you make the first choice above

void pmm()
{
    cout << "d - Deposit Money" << endl;
    cout << "w - Withdraw Money" << endl;
    cout << "r - Request Balance" << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
}

//this is to login to the account

void login()
{
    cout << "Okay, you're in" << endl;
}

// this is to create an account

void createa()
{
    int id = 0;
    int password = 0;

    cout << "create an ID of two numbers" << endl;
    cin >> id;

    cout << "Make a password of 4 numbers" << endl;
    cin >> password;
}

// Starts and is basically the entire project

int start(void (*x)(), void (*y)(), void (*z)())
{
    x();

    char choice = '\0';

    cout << "Enter the choice that you want:";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'l':
            y();
            break;
        case 'c':
            z();
            break;
        case 'q':
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "This is not a command" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, unless "function pointers" is the actual topic you are studying at the moment, then this is a very questionable design, even for a simple homework assignment.  It would be cleaner and easier to read/manage to just call the functions directly instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// these should have all of my declared functions

int start();
void pim();
void pmm();
void login();
void createa();

//my assignment wants me to have only one function used

int main()
{
    start();

    return 0;
}

//This should be the start of the code

void pim()
{
    cout << "Please select a letter from the menu below:" << endl;
    cout << "l - Login" << endl;
    cout << "c - Create New Account" << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
}

// this is to post a menu after you make the first choice above

void pmm()
{
    cout << "d - Deposit Money" << endl;
    cout << "w - Withdraw Money" << endl;
    cout << "r - Request Balance" << endl;
    cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
}

//this is to login to the account

void login()
{
    cout << "Okay, you're in" << endl;
}

// this is to create an account

void createa()
{
    int id = 0;
    int password = 0;

    cout << "create an ID of two numbers" << endl;
    cin >> id;

    cout << "Make a password of 4 numbers" << endl;
    cin >> password;
}

// Starts and is basically the entire project

int start()
{
    pim();

    char choice = '\0';

    cout << "Enter the choice that you want:";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'l':
            login();
            break;
        case 'c':
            createa();
            break;
        case 'q':
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "This is not a command" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```